# "Заработать денег" или "заработать деньги"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, управление

***Тогда они договорились учиться по очереди, а перед этим заработать денег в качестве гувернанток.***

В последние годы стало очень распространённым выражение ***заработать денег***. Насколько оно корректно?

Comment: См. https://www.ekburg.ru/news/18/61418-kak-pravilno-zarabotat-dengi-ili-deneg/

Comment: См. http://gramota.ru/forum/kurilka/53798/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выражение **корректно** и применяется в случаях, когда деньги зарабатывают *не с конкретной целью* (нужную или известную сумму на что-то - "**заработать деньги на...**"), а сколько удастся, "на жизнь", либо речь может идти о деньгах, которых заведомо не хватит на планируемую покупку, но которые будут использованы на неё как *часть необходимых средств*. Вероятное происхождение выражения: упрощение выражения "*заработать [некоторое количество или часть необходимых] **денег***".

Comment: Спасибо, Alex_ander!

Answer (score 2):

Грамотно и *заработать **(что?)** деньги*, и *заработать **(чего?)** денег*.

Источник — "Словарь сочетаемости слов русского языка"; М.: Русский язык, 1983.

Comment: Заработать и зарабатывать - не одно и то же. *Зарабатывать что- ~ деньги, какую-л. сумму [денег] ... заработать (только сов.) чего: денег* (Словарь сочетаемости слов русского языка)

Comment: @М_Г Если вы внимательно прочитаете статью, то увидите, что это видовые формы одного и того же глагола. ***Зарабатывать** денег* словарь не разрешает, поэтому и пишет: "Зарабатывать что: ~ деньги, какую-л. сумму [денег] ...; заработать ***(только сов.)*** чего: ~ денег ..."

Comment: @М_Г Словарь вовсе не запрещает "заработать деньги"! Про особенности употребления вариантов я не говорю. Вопрос был о корректности род. п.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, Aer!